# ng-enter not loading in when content loads angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angularjs application which loads content from Instagram, however, on page load I would like to fade the loaded content in with a smooth transition.

I added `{{ loadedClass }}` to the main HTML tag but it doesn't seem to place ng-enter within it when it loads:

**HTML**

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <section ng-controller="ShowImages as images" class="page {{ loadedClass }}" ng-view>
```

**CSS**

```
.page.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
  animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
}

/* line 697, ../sass/app.scss */
.page.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 2s both ease-in;
  animation: fadeIn 2s both ease-in;
}
```

**Controller

```
 var app = angular.module('instafeed', ['ngAnimate']);
    app.filter('getFirstCommentFrom',function(){
  return function(arr, user){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i].from.username==user)
        return arr[i].text;
    }
    return '';
  }
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

See here:
http://machinas.com/wip/machinas/instagramfeed/

I get this console error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $animate <- $compile
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24qProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24q%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile


return new Error(message);
```

Comment: I looked into the link you posted it seems to me that you have a mess of unclosed/missing `{ }` and `( )`. It's not causing the error that you mention here but something else.

Comment: that's fixed, but I just don't get why ng-enter is being added in on load :(

Answer (score 0):

The class 'page' should go on each of your  item, not the container:

```
<ul ng-show="layout == 'grid'" class="page grid"> 
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

That is the `ul` who are entering and leaving when you change tabs, not the `section`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing how events work, your `ng-view` is in the same level as `ng-controller` so when the event is emitted it doesn't "see" it. When events are emitted they are emmited to its parents.

I suggest the following in your HTML:

```
<section ng-controller="ShowImages as images" class="page {{ loadedClass }}" >
    <div ng-view>
        <!-- The rest of your code -->
    </div>
</section>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I mislead you. I confused `$emit` with `$broadcast`.

**EDIT 2**

Looking at your HTML, you are not using ng-views correctly. The ng-views are supposed to be used together routes. That explains why the event is not firing. In your code, you are not loading a view at all.

**EDIT 3**

Look into animating the ng-cloak directive; you will be able to achieve just about the same result without views. What you are trying to do is not very complex and you seem to be starting out so I recommend skipping ng-view for now :)

Comment: tried that but the problem seems to be that it's not adding ng-enter as a class

Comment: @user1937021 I've edited my answer. The main issue is that you're not using ng-views correctly.

Comment: So it should fire event with the html set as you have posted above?

Comment: @user1937021 No, it won't. The main issue is that just setting the `ng-view` attribute doesn't make what's inside it a view. It must be wired with routes for it to work. Look into animating the `ng-cloak` directive; you will be able to achieve just about the same result without views.